# Multiple Functions on a .on() without impacting scope

Tags: jquery, function, scope, onclick, this

I am currently making a dynamic webpage and trying to run multiple functions whenever the element with the class=application is clicked. The below code works but it's very repetitive.

```
$(document).on("click", ".application", renderImage);
$(document).on("click", ".application", renderText);
$(document).on("click", ".application", renderCodeButton);
$(document).on("click", ".application", renderAppButton);
```

I attempted to put these functions within one master function and run that with the .on() however as I use $(this).attr to pull information nesting the render functions within a master function ruins the scope.

Here is the renderImage function, though they are all very similar:

```
function renderImage () {
  $(".appPicture").empty();
  console.log(this);
  let applicationPic = $(this).attr("data-image")
  let img = $("<img>");
  img.addClass("appPic")
  img.attr("src", applicationPic);
  $(".appPicture").append(img);
}
```

Is there a way to run multiple functions with a single click event or a way to nest functions within a master without impacting the scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".application", function(){
    let scope = this;
    renderImage(scope);
    renderText(scope);
    renderCodeButton(scope);
    renderAppButton(scope);
});

function renderImage (scope) {
    $(".appPicture").empty();
    console.log(scope);
    let applicationPic = $(scope).attr("data-image")
    let img = $("<img>");
    img.addClass("appPic")
    img.attr("src", applicationPic);
    $(".appPicture").append(img);
}
```

you can do something like this

Comment: I've tried that but it changes the scope so $(this) is no longer the item I am clicking but is instead window.

Comment: i edit the answer, your function should have args that accept the scope you want..

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you.